# SQL problem with JOIN statement (multiple results from 1 table)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a SQL query that selects quiz_questions and quiz_question_options
But when I run my SQL query I only get 1 result from quiz_option (in my database I have 3 options for each question). How would I be able to display all 3 options for every question?

Tables:

quiz_question

`-id (PK)
  -quiz_id(FK)
  -question`

quiz_question_option

```
`-id (PK)
-quiz_question_id(FK)
-quiz_option`
```

This is my code so far:

`SELECT quiz_question.question,quiz_question_option.quiz_option
FROM quiz_question_option
LEFT JOIN quiz_question
ON quiz_question.id = quiz_question_option.quiz_question_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`

The limit will change depending on user input

EDIT:
The result i get is:

`question  |quiz_option
 1.question|1.answer
 2.question|2.answer`

What I need to get is:

`question  |quiz_option
1.question|1.answer
1.question|2.asnwer
1.question|3.answer
2.question|1.answer
2.question|2.answer
3.question|3.answer
etc...`

2.EDIT: 
I need to make a sql query for my project (website)
so the user will select how many questions he wants to have.
On the next page it would display the questions. I already have the code to display random questions. But I don't know how to display the options for the selected question.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: It's obviously not possible that that query could produce that result, so there's something you're not telling us

Answer (score 1):

seems you want to ignore the relationship. what you want to achieve is something like `cross join`

```
select t1.question, t2.quiz_option
from quiz_question_option t1
cross join quiz_question t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe INNER join would help you. 
Try this:

```
SELECT quiz_question.question, quiz_question_option.quiz_option
FROM quiz_question_option AS O
INNER JOIN quiz_question AS Q
ON Q.id= O.quiz_question_id
```

Comment: This works not - at least not without a little bit of editing